# Getting the list of followers with there attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have two classes

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followers
  has_many :contacts, :through => :followers
end
```

and

```
class Follower < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contact, :class_name => "user", :foreign_key => "contact_id" 
end
```

I want to get all the followers attributes (name, surname, address etc.) from a User.

when I try `User.first.followers` I got the good list.

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Follower id: 1, user_id: 1
, contact_id: 2, created_at: "2016-05-02 14:01:35", updated_at: "2016-05-02 14:0
1:35">]>
```

When I do `User.first.contacts` it fails with this error `NameError: uninitialized constant User::user`

How could I do to get there followers attributes like a `User.all` do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NameError: uninitialized constant User::user

You have a ***wrong value*** for `:class_name` option for the `belongs_to :contact` in the `follower` model. It should be `User` not `user`

```
class Follower < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contact, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "contact_id" 
end
```